# Отобрать определенное количество записей в листе R

Tags: r

У меня есть датасет baseball из библиотеки plyr. Нужно отобрать те команды, где есть 200 и больше записей и записать это в матрицу, взяв по 200 записей у каждой команды.
У меня получилось только отсортировать, а как действовать дальше не понятно. Класс и тип переменной teams - list

```
library(plyr)
baseball
teams = split(baseball, baseball$team)
teams
```

Comment: `а как действовать дальше не понятно` — дальше произведите декомпозицию стоящей перед вами задачи (фактически у вас это **уже** получилось — во второй фразе вопроса). и попробуйте последовательно решить эти под-задачи. а когда возникнут **конкретные** трудности — добро пожаловать с **конкретными** вопросами.

Comment: Конкретно дальше вопрос в том как сделать, чтобы отобразись по 200 записей из каждой команды

Comment: 1. а перед этим ещё один вопрос: «отобрать те команды, где есть 200 и больше записей». 2. но если вам остался непонятен лишь вопрос о том, как вывести только по n строк из таблицы для каждого значения переменной x — то вот этот конкретный вопрос и задайте, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите справку по функциям библиотеки plyr. match_df делает почти то что Вы хотите и даже с тем же датасетом.
Отобрать команды можно так:

```
library(dplyr)
fdf<-ddply(baseball, "team", summarise,id = length(unique(id)))
fdf<-fdf%>% dplyr::filter(id > 199)
bb_longterm <- match_df(baseball, fdf, on="team")
bb_longterm[1:5,]
```